# why show a running device is empty when run app to show logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a new in android development.
I installed Android Studio yesterday.
my question is

```
why when I try to run logcat ,get no device on dialog box of [choose device] 
option >> 
choose a running device.
```

the strange thing is -

```
I have avd [Nexus 5 API 21 x86] but appears only in dialog box of [choose device]   
option >> 
launch emulator.
```

my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public static final String MY_TAG = "The_Custom_Message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(MY_TAG,"on_Create");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// ... etc
```

The_Custom_Message is my logcat filter tag
and my logcat filter name is MyMessages

please help me ... what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> why when I try to run logcat ,get no device on dialog box of [choose
>   device]

You can create an Android Virtual Device.
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

> I have avd [Nexus 5 API 21 x86] but appears only in dialog box of [choose device]

You can use this AVD [Nexus 5 API 21 x86] to test your application if you don´t have any physical device connected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect a mobile device to the machine to be able to see a device in the DDMS perspective. 
Also, make sure the USB Debugging option is enabled for the device you are trying to see.

Comment: that is meen logcat not enable to run on avd (virtual device) ?

Comment: Logcat always runs on Android studio, whether you use a physical device or an AVD